# How can I create a female jumper wire connector

Tags: connector

How can I create the female side of wires like these to fit 2.54mm spaced headers? What would the part inside the enclosure be and what is the name of the enclosure? I'm struggling to find them on UK suppliers' websites.

[image: Headers]

Comment: Keywords: "ebay" and "china"

Answer (score 7, accepted):

How about [these](http://www.adafruit.com/products/266) female-female wires, 6" long:

[image]

[image]

Comment: I changed the question significantly because it was too broad, but your answer was good so thank you.

Comment: +1. After I've cut, filed, soldered and heat-shrinked a single 4-wire cable in DIY-style, I purchased two sets of these (from a different supplier).

Answer (score 12):

These connectors are called 'DuPont' connectors and you can get them cheap on ebay shipped from China. Search for 'dupont connectors' or 'dupont wires'.

Comment: I find this a little hard to believe, since DuPont is a large company that makes many things.  I wasn't aware they made connectors, but if they do, I'd be surprised to find they make only one model.

Comment: @OlinLathrop: Despite this, a cursory check on ebay does find them.

Comment: @OlinLathrop Dupont makes other connectors, but when I wanted to buy crimp sockets and housings for these, I had to search for Dupont connectors. (From what I've read,) What they actually are are slightly lower quality knockoffs of Dupont's connects, and aren't compatible, but look the same. As for if Dupont actually makes something like this, I don't know, but even though Molex makes many different kinds of connectors, when the PC community says "Molex connector", they generally refer to the [AMP MATE-N-LOK Series](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Molex_connector).

Comment: @OlinLathrop it's a bit like the use of brand name "Hoover" to refer to a vacuum cleaner, the name [DuPont connector](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jump_wire) is widely used.

Answer (score 7):

A DIY solution you can do with stuff usually flying around an electronics lab:

You could try using female single-row pinheaders, pitched at 2.54 mm, separeate them with a knife (sacrificing one contact where you cut) and solder wires to them.

[image: Pinheader, female]

[Image Source](http://www.digitalo.de/products/282537/Buchsenleisten-in-Einloettechnik-RM-2-54-gerade-Serie-BL-1...-R.html)

Insulation, if desired, may be done with heat shrink tubes.

Comment: Note that the header shown has turned pins, which are much thinner than the 0.64 mm squared many/most PCB headers use. A 0.64 mm pin will not fit in it.

Comment: @stevenvh and others, thanks for catching this. I found a better example picture.

Comment: This sounds like a good idea, these look reasonable from Farnell: http://www.farnell.com/datasheets/12112.pdf

Comment: @oscode - The ones in the pdf of your link are like the ones I had in my first picture (now edited). As stevenvh pointed out, these precision contacts are very good if you use them for pins that fit the specs. If, however, your pins are bigger than specified for the contacts, they won't fit. For your purpose, it is probably better to stick with the cheaper spring contacts.

Answer (score 5):

You can create your own using a crimp socket.

[image]

Available from [Farnell](http://uk.farnell.com/harwin/m20-1180046/crimp-socket-tin-22-30awg-pk100/dp/1022220) at £5.74 for a pack of 100.

Comment: +1 for crimp socket. If you have extras lying around, check that they fit the header pin size, and crimp onto a wire. You can use heatshrink to insulate the bare metal so nothing is exposed.

Comment: That's surprisingly expensive

Answer (score 1):

Trim down [female molex connectors](http://www.rapidonline.com/Cables-Connectors/2-54mm-KK-PCB-Connectors-66414), do it with a craft knife watch your fingers, and you'll need the crimps to hold the wire in and that would do the job.

Answer (score 0):

You can try these from [dealextreme](http://dx.com/p/jst-cables-10-pair-15234). They come in male/female bundles. The female part has a small bump on one side so you cannot connect them side-by-side to e.g. 10×2 header, but you can easily connect a single one to 1×2 goldpin header or connect them to every second pair in bigger headers.

[image]