# How can I create female-to-female jumper wires from female-to-male jumper wires?

Tags: jumper

In a similar spirit to [this question](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/37783/how-can-i-create-a-female-jumper-wire-connector), I want to create female to female jumper wires.  However, I only have individual female to male jumper wires and I don't really want to go out and buy new wires.  I hypothesize that there might be a way to remove the female end from one wire and connect it to the other to create a female-to-female jumper wire.  How can I best accomplish this?

Comment: How does this question differ from that one?

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams: My question focuses on creating them solely from female-to-male jumper wires.  The other question was more open ended and none of the answers seemed to address creation from other female-to-male jumper wires specifically.  At least, not in my opinion.

Comment: Cut and crimp new terminals. And the other question covers the crimp part.

Answer (score 2):

Cut and solder. Heatshrink to taste. There is really no smart alternative if buying new isn't an option.

Answer (score 1):

Yes you could make one, but Ebay is cheap for stuff like that. For most gauge wires can use wire ties or twisty caps make the easiest just fine connection. New wires do not twist well like earbud headset type wires and solder would be best.

Comment: "Twisty caps"... Do you mean marrettes?